# Чтение и создание датафрэйма из .s2p файлов

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

[[image: данные из файла][1]][image: нужно такую таблицу но почему то у мой код не использовал информацию из файла]Здравствуйте. Мне нужно прочитать .s2p файл в питоне и создать датафрыйм из таких файлов. Я пробивал использовать пандас код как и на csv, но недоучилось. И в инете нашел библатеку skrf-rf но не смог создать пандас дарафрэйм.

Comment: https://scikit-rf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/generated/skrf.network.Network.to_dataframe.html?highlight=to_pandas

Comment: Я использовал но мой файл состоит из 9 столбцов а команда ntwk.to_dataframe имеет 4 столба и первый столб идет как нумерация.

Comment: Считайте его как текст и передайте тому же csvreader. Непонятно, почему pandas не справился - код и ошибки приведите. Структура данных то простая

Comment: Приведите пожалуйста в вопросе [mcve] входных данных (__в виде текста / CSV / Python кода или ссылки на файл__) и __то что вы ожидаете получить на выходе__. Также советую ознакомиться: [Как наиболее эффективно задать вопрос, связанный с обработкой и/или анализом данных (например: по Pandas / Numpy / SciPy / SciKit Learn / SQL)](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7060/)

Comment: А покажите, что в `df` перед строкой, где вы колонки выставляете.

Comment: https://photos.app.goo.gl/x4a8J2kpBY3cMxT8A